# C++ QT Getting part from QString

Tags: qt, qstring, qtgui

I have custom(dynamic QString) for example something like this 123+555 and i need to get this after +.Also there can be something different then + (/,*,- etc.). My question is how to get part of string after some char.

Comment: QString::split works fine in this case.  If you need more control, look up QRegularExpression.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [split](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#split) function, which allows you to specify the separator and returns a list of the elements.

```
QString string("123+555");
QStringList listItems = string.split('+', QString::SkipEmptyParts);
QString finalString = listItems[1];
```

Alternatively, you can [find by index](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#indexOf-3) the separating character location and use that with a call to [right](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#right)

Comment: Can you give me a little more information, i dont thing that i understand how to get  just one part, here is presented with list...

Comment: After the split, you'll have a list of 2 items [123, 555]. The final line references the 2nd item in the list, which is the string after the '+'

Answer (score 0):

Since you're usin Qt, you could try the class: [QRegExp](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html).

With such class you could write code like this:

```
// This code was not tested.
QRegExp rx("(\\d+)(\\+|\\-|\\*|/)(\\d+)");  // Be aware, I recommend you to read the link above in order to see how construct the proper regular expression.
int pos = rx.indexIn("23+344");
if (pos > -1) {
    QString number_1 = rx.cap(1);  // "23"
    QString op       = rx.cap(2);  // "+"
    QString number_2 = rx.cap(3);  // "344"
    // ...
}
```

This way you don't have to write code to check which of the characters(operators) "+, -, *, /" is present to then perform a split on the string depending on what character was found.